# how to get rid of Visual Studio annotations

Tags: visual-studio, c++11

i cant seem to find how to get ride of it
iv tried googling it but cant find a good answer, its really starting to bug me

every time i try to compile also it automatically  goes to that and i really dont want it to do that also

[image: pic of the it]

Comment: You get rid of these message by *fixing the errors* that they point out. A pointer to `char` (i.e. `char*`) is not the same as an array of pointers to char (i.e. `char*[70]`). For this error perhaps you meant to have an array of `char` (not an array of pointers)?

Comment: these arnt errors, just warnings and they arnt really effecting me so i just want they overlay to be gone

Comment: And you don't get errors (or warnings) when actually *building* the source? Because you *should* be getting errors (or warnings) then too. And the solution is still to fix the root cause which is the incompatible types (in the example shown).

Comment: In short: You get these messages because there's something wrong in your code that you need to fix.